# Initialization of std::array with function pointer member function of constexpr object

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to initialize an std::array of function pointers. These pointers point to member functions of an already instantiated object.

Can somebody please help with the following example? Many thanks in advance!

```
#include <array>

using TVoidVoid = void (*)(void);

class Foo {
public:
  constexpr Foo() {}
  void myHandler() {}
};

class Bar {
public:
  constexpr Bar() : handler_{nullptr} {}
  constexpr Bar(TVoidVoid handler) : handler_{handler} {}

private:
  TVoidVoid handler_;
};

Foo f;
std::array<Bar, 5> bar_array = {{Bar{}, Bar{f.myHandler}}};

int main() {}
```

compiling produces:

```
main.cpp:22:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘Bar::Bar(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
std::array<Bar, 5> bar_array = {{Bar{}, Bar{f.myHandler}}};
```

I am using `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`.

Comment: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function. Also `TVoidVoid` would be `void (Foo::*)(void)` instead of `void (*)(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers to free functions are handled differently than pointers to member functions. The `TVoidVoid` type is a pointer to a free function, but you need a pointer to a `Foo` member function. Hence, define `Foo` first,

```
class Foo { /* As before... */ };
```

*then* go with a type alias for the member function (`Foo` must be known at this point)

```
// Note the different syntax to the former TVoidVoid
using FooVoidVoid = void (Foo::*)();
```

Next, `Bar` must be adjusted such that its data member is of type `FooVoidVoid` and the constructor accepts this type as an argument (the rest of `Bar` can be left as it is), and finally defined the array as

```
std::array<Bar, 3> bar_array = {{Bar{}, Bar{&Foo::myHandler}}};
```

Note that `&Foo::myHandler` has nothing to do with any existing `Foo` instance. It's just a pointer to a `Foo` member function, and only when you invoke it, this must be brought together with a `Foo` object (the special operators `.*` and `->*` are meant for this to happen, or use `std::invoke` once you upgrade to a C++17-enabled compiler).